# activerecord, nested categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested, relationship, categories

If I have a nested categories, where each category might have many sub-categories, and each category belongs to one parent category, how would I write the Category model ?

I thought it will be something like this:

```
Category
belongs_to :category 
has_many   :categories
```

where I have `parent_category_id` in the category table, is this a good relationship ? or do I need a second table to present a many to many relationship ? I think I need some thing like belongs_to_and_has_many ?

Any guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :parent, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class => "Category"
has_many :categories, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class => "Category"

# Uses parent_id for the association.
```

`has_and_belongs_to_many` and a second table are not needed or appropriate for mapping this kinda structure.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the same as the example for `acts_as_tree`.

Check out https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree

All you need is the `parent_id` column and you can say;

```
class Category
  include ActsAsTree
  acts_as_tree :order => "name"
end
```

You'll then have access to the following;

```
category.parent   # your parent
category.children # all the categories you are parent of
category.root     # the parent of any parents (or yourself)
category.ancestor # your parent, grandparent, ...
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, very interesting to know about such a plugin, although I wonder if there is a gem version for it ?

Comment: it is a gem... they jut got the readme wrong. it used to be a plugin a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

While Michael Durrant's answer is indeed correct, the `foreign_key` can be inferred in the `belongs_to` call. The same applies to the `class` in the `has_many` call.

As such, a more concise version of Michael Durrant's answer:

```rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category'
  has_many :categories, foreign_key: :parent_id

  # Uses `parent_id` for the association
end
```